# When not entering any value, my program crashes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem in my windows form in c#. The program is simple;
there are 3 textboxes and then it sums their values. however, when i click on the sum button without entering any values in the other 3 textboxes, the program crashes.

How can i make these textboxes accept only positive numbers and zeros?
this is what i did

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double FirstNumb = Convert.ToDouble(txtFirstValue.Text);
        double SecondNumb = Convert.ToDouble(txtSecondValue.Text);
        double ThirdNumb = Convert.ToDouble(txtThirdValue.Text);

        double m;

        m = FirstNumb + SecondNumb + ThirdNumb;
        listBox1.Items.Add(m);


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide more information in order to get more help. For example: what code is executed when you click the sum button?

Comment: You should post your code, so we don't need to guess to help you. But if your code expects some number to make summation, then it's only natural the app will crash, if it receives "" from textbox. Empty string can't be added.

Comment: You are probably calling `int.Parse()` (or something like that) which will throw an exception on invalid input. Tip: the empty string is invalid input. You should either use `TryParse()` or else validate the data prior to parsing.

Comment: Show the code of your click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check that the string value from the text box is not null or empty, or otherwise invalid.  Change this line:

`double FirstNumb = Convert.ToDouble(txtFirstValue.Text);`

to this

```
double FirstNumb = 0;
double.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text, out FirstNumb);
```

FirstNumb will remain 0 if the parsing fails.  Note that TryParse returns a bool, true if the parsing was successful and false otherwise.  You can also take action on that as well, perhaps showing a MessageBox asking the user to fill a value and exiting the summation method.

See the documentation for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:  If you want to enforce only positive values, after the try parse you'll have to check that FirstNumb >= 0 and use a MessageBox to alert the user why, and abort the summation method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolve using `int.TryParse`. This handles string as well.

[Demo Reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse)

Comment: Don't rely on external links to provide the bulk of your answer, as the link may become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely trying to convert the textboxes textual content to int. Unfortunately, you cannot convert an empty string to a number. Try setting the textboxes default content to "0".

Comment: can you explain more plz :(